# R Buffer/Enlarge a polygon

Tags: r

I have a simple polygon.

```
dfr <- data.frame(x=c(2,2.5,4,5,4.5,3,2),y=c(2,3,3.5,3,2.8,2.5,2))
plot(dfr)
polygon(dfr)
```

[image]

Are there any R functions to increase the size of the polygon equally in all directions?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `sf` package you can convert your polygon to a spatial object and use `st_buffer`:

```
> p = st_polygon(list(as.matrix(dfr)))
> pbuf = st_buffer(p, .4)
> plot(pbuf)
> plot(p,add=TRUE,col="red")
>
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to not use one of the large GIS package as a dependency. But, I guess this works. Perhaps I could take this function apart. There should really be a simple geometry package that works on basic R objects.

Comment: Any simple geometry package will expand to include GIS :)

Answer (score 0):

For pure plotting purpose, I found this solution.

```
library(ggplot2)
dfr <- data.frame(x=c(2,2.5,4,5,4.5,3,2),y=c(2,3,3.5,3,2.8,2.5,2))

# vanilla polygon
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_polygon(fill=NA,col="black")+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```
# enlarge polygon
library(ggforce)
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_polygon(fill=NA,col="black")+
  geom_shape(fill=NA,col="red",expand=unit(0.2,"cm"))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```
# enlarge with pretty curved edges
library(ggforce)
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_polygon(fill=NA,col="black")+
  geom_shape(fill=NA,col="red",expand=unit(0.2,"cm"),radius=unit(0.2,"cm"))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Note that `ggforce 0.1.3` version on CRAN does not have this feature yet. The version on [GitHub](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce) has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

A lightweight implementation using the native plotting functions is available in the [`GrowPolygon()`](https://ms609.github.io/Ternary/dev/reference/Polygon-Geometry.html) function, available in the the "[Ternary](https://ms609.github.io/Ternary/)" R package since version 2.1.0 (presently available via `install.github("ms609/Ternary")`, and coming soon to CRAN).

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = c(2,2.5,4,5,4.5,3,2), y = c(2,3,3.5,3,2.8,2.5,2))
plot(dfr)
polygon(dfr)
polygon(Ternary::GrowPolygon(dfr, buffer = 0.2), border = 2)
```

[image]